# hide the empty spaces between text , textfield and button

Tags: html, css

please visit [link](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/say-cheese-pink-apple-iphone-6s-phone-case.html)

here you can see as in below image :

[image]

I want to hide the empty spaces  present between "Text1", "Textfield" & "check" button.

also empty spaces present between 2 horizontal lines.

I want to display "check" button right next to Text field".

i tried using "`position : relative ; right: 200px;` "

but it affected on other parts of the page.

```
.block-check-delivery .block-title strong {background-image:none; font-size: 11px;}
.block-check-delivery .block-content {padding:0 10px;  }
.block-check-delivery .button {float: right;}
.block-check-delivery input{width: 107px;}
```

i want to display like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upHbj.png)

Comment: Cannot visit link.

Comment: See how have you posted it.

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div class="block-title" style="
    display: inline-block;
">
                <strong><span>Check Availability at</span></strong>
    </div>
<div class="block-content" style="
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
">        
        <br>
            <input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" id="zipcode" value="" maxlength="10" class="input-text" placeholder="Enter ZIP Code">
            <button type="button" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span>Check</span></button>
            <div id="delivery-message"></div>
                        <div id="delivery-html"></div>

        <br>        
    </div>
```

Does your requirement[image]

Comment: you can see there are 2 horizontal lines are displaying above "check delivery availabilty" text, i want to remove one horizontal line here : http://prnt.sc/awm3wj

Comment: .block-title {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-top: none;
    display: inline-block;
}   .std ul {
    list-style: disc outside;
    /* margin-bottom: 1.5em; */
}

Comment: please checjk now one more line is displaying.

Comment: do you want to remove bottom one too

Comment: remove the <hr> tag above <!-- check delivery end--> line that will remove that

Comment: that <hr> tag is for line present below. i want to remove the line which is present above.

Comment: Thats what i  have told already, 
`.block-title { position: relative; padding: 10px 0 0; margin-bottom: 5px; border-top: none; display: inline-block; } .std ul { list-style: disc outside; /* margin-bottom: 1.5em; */ } `,, this is what you want right http://prntscr.com/awmhxo  if you need horizontal line dont remove that <hr>

Comment: its worked frine, is it possible to hide little more empty spaces presnt below and above button.

Comment: `.product-view .product-shop .short-description {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    clear: both;
}  .block, .col-left-first {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}` You can remove margin bottom  completely if you dont need space

Comment: in textfield, please enter zip code : 000000 and click on "check" button.

now "text is displaying below. please help me to display text above as like [here](http://totaltoys.com/delete-10.html)

Comment: Do like this, bring that container out of block-content http://prntscr.com/awmsab

Comment: ar you telling em to change "delivery-html" to "delivery-message".

Comment: can you please tell how i can fix it after enter pin code ?

Comment: `<div class="block-content">        
        <br>
            <input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" id="zipcode" value="" maxlength="10" class="input-text" placeholder="Enter ZIP Code">
            <button type="button" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span>Check</span></button>
            
                        <div id="delivery-html"></div>

        <br>        
    </div>  <div id="delivery-message" style="color: red;">Cash on delivery is not available</div>`  Do like this, just brought that div outside

Comment: i tried `float:left;` to .block-title, it worked for me, thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

The button has a CSS rule:

```css
.block-check-delivery .button {
  float: right;
}
```

That's the one causing the trouble. Remove the `float: right` rule and it will be alright.

Comment: please check link, i want to display like this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/upHbj.png , means displaying "check avaialabilty at" text in same line as "textfield" and button.

Comment: also please help me to reduce the empty spaces above and below button

Answer (score 0):

The space is generated by a `<br>` element you can hide using CSS with the following rule:

```
.block-check-delivery .block-content > br:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

Then

```
.block-check-delivery .block-title {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 0;
}
```

Also the button should have

```
.block-check-delivery .button {
  float: left;
}
```

And I would suggest you to try out also this rule to fix the design:

```
.block-check-delivery .block-content > br:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

Generally speaking using `<br>` elements to create space between elements is a bad design pattern. I would like you to rely on `padding` and `margin` rules and remove those `<br>` elements from your HTML markup.

Comment: please check link now, i want to display like this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/upHbj.png means displaying "check avaialabilty at" text in same line as "textfield" and button

Answer (score 0):

With these two styles the result appears to be correct ... then you can play with the margins on the "block-title" or on the "check" button.

```
.block-title {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    // border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; // remove this...
    border: none !important; // Add this
    display: inline-block; // <----- ADD THIS
}
.block-content {
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block; // <----- ADD THIS
}
```

This is the image result...

[image]

Comment: please help me to remove the line above "check delivery availabilty" text : http://prnt.sc/awm4x6

Comment: @ng369 
You just need to remove the " border-top " on css style ".block -title" :)

Comment: i removed it, please check link , now one more line is displaying.

Comment: @ng369 Ok , you have another style that overwrites border on ".block-title" , then , force the style of ".block-title" adding "border: none;" and if you want to be absolutely sure , use " border:none !important;".

Comment: i tried like this : `border-top: none ; !important` but it didt worked

Comment: please check link now. now text is displaying above.

Comment: @ng369 sure, you've removed "display:inline-block;" from ".block-title". Compare my answer (especially the style of ".block-title") with your css ... make sure it's the same.

Comment: @ng369 If I helped you, and the answer is correct ... mark it as correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove  Div class="block-title" and place strong tag in the Div class="block-content".
also remove br tag